# c# RegExp shows only one capture

Tags: c#, regex

```
private String pattern = @"^{(.*)|(.*)}$";
ret = groups[0].Captures.Count.ToString(); // returns 1
```

isn't it should return 2 captures? because I have two `()` in my RegExp?

my string for example:

```
{test1 | test2}
```

the first capture should be `test1` and the secnd `test2`, but I get the whole string in return and the captures count is 1 why is that?

**UPDATE:**

```
     Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(_sourceString);
     String ret = "";
     foreach (Match match in matches)
     {
         GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
         ret = groups[0].Captures[0].Value;
     }

     return ret; //returns the whole string, but I've expected 'test1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` has a special meaning in regular expression. `A|B` matches `A` or `B`.

To match `|` literally, you need to escape it:

```
@"^{(.*)\|(.*)}$";
```

Comment: hmmm...I have edited that, but I've still get 1 count of Captures and in return I get the whole string

Comment: @yeahitsme, Please update your question with missing code (`groups = ...`)

Comment: @yeahitsme, Try `Console.WriteLine(groups[1]); Console.WriteLine(groups[2]);`.

Comment: @yeahitsme, And `Console.WriteLine(groups.Count)`. It will print 3. (1 for entire matched string, 2 for each group)